# How to do full text search in DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, full-text-search, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) for displaying the data.

In this by default I have Search box at the top right corner, but search is not working as I expected.

E.g.

Let's say I have records as

```
$ 50
$ 52
$ 45
$ 41
$ 53
```

When I type `$ 5`, It shows me all records. This is happening because it searches $ and 5 separately.

Any idea how to do full text search?

Result with search `$ 5` expected is

```
$ 50
$ 52
$ 53
```

Any idea how to get this done through jQuery for datatable...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation: the oSearch option
https://www.datatables.net/usage/options

oSearch

This parameter allows you to have define the global filtering state at initialisation time. As an object the "sSearch" parameter must be defined, but all other parameters are optional. When "bRegex" is true, the search string will be treated as a regular expression, when false (default) it will be treated as a straight string. When "bSmart" DataTables will use it's smart filtering methods (to word match at any point in the data), when false this will not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery DataTable is a great plugin and provides more efficient features. this plugin split the original string using the space character and searches all records for each item. For example, if the string is`$ 5`, They will search by `$` and `5` separately.

I also looking similar things and spent more hours finding the solution. I have
created a custom filter like this and code working well:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
                var filter = $("#dynamic-table1_filter input").val().trim().toLowerCase();
                for (var d = 0; d < aData.length; d++) {
                    if (aData[d].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```